# React : Callback value received in parent not passing the latest value in another child as prop | Function component

Tags: reactjs, callback, setstate, react-props, react-functional-component

I am using function component:

I have 1 Parent and 2 child components.

Child 1 passing data to parent via call back. In parent the callback values are received and using `setState` it is assigning to a variable, and sent to child 2 correctly.

However when child 1 does any change and passes data to parent via callback, Parent is not passing the latest value in another child component as prop. Still showing old values.

Pictorial Illustration:

[image]

Sample Code :

```
const ContainerComponent = (props) => {
    let [selectedCenterId, setSelectedCenterId] = useState("");

    const callbackFromServiceDetails = (centerId) => {
        setSelectedCenterId((selectedCenterId = centerId));
        console.log("Inside parent callback");
        console.log(selectedCenterId);
    };

  return (  
      <>
        <ChildComponent1 activeTab={activeTab} parentCallback={callbackFromServiceDetails}></ChildComponent1>
        {
            selectedCenterId !== "" ?
            <ChildComponent2 activeTab={activeTab} selectedCenterId={selectedCenterId}></ChildComponent2>
            :
            <></>
        }
      </>
   );
};

export default ContainerComponent;


========================================================================

const ChildComponent1 = ({centersNLocations, actions, ...props}) => {

    const nextButtonClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.parentCallback(selectedCenter);
      };

    return (
        <>
        ...
        </>
    );
};



ChildComponent1.propTypes = {
  ...
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    ...
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      ...
    }
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ChildComponent1);



=====================================

const ChildComponent2 = (props) => {
    let [centerId, setCenterId] = useState(props.selectedCenterId);
    console.log(centerId);

    return (
        <>
        ...
        </>
    );
};

export default ChildComponent2;
```

Any ideas what could cause such issue?

Comment: can you provides some code bro!

Comment: Add the relevant parts of the code

Comment: @JatinParmar Added sample Code

Comment: I have tested your code it's working fine

Comment: somehow its not passing correct values in second change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that issue is in the parent component code as you change the reference from useState to the value itself. It line `setSelectedCenterId((selectedCenterId = centerId));` you **should not** use **equal** operator so your function should looks like:

```js
  const callbackFromServiceDetails = (centerId) => {
        setSelectedCenterId(centerId);
        console.log("Inside parent callback");
        console.log(selectedCenterId);
    };
```

Tip for future: Use `const` instead of `let` if you want to keep reference not changed.

Comment: I want the updated values, hence putting const will not let the data change, I hope that's correct

Comment: You can have const and it will be updated value there don't worry. But your primary fault was having assignment in the code so basically this line was faulty: ```setSelectedCenterId((selectedCenterId = centerId));```